# Fill an Array in C in a spiral way

Tags: c, arrays, spiral

Okay i have to do a program that fills an array in a spiral way like this

```
1  2  5  10 
4  3  6  11 
9  8  7  12 
16 15 14 13
```

Its not like a normal spiral that begins from the center so im having some trouble with it. The positions for where the data will be stored should be like

```
array[0] [0] 
array[0] [1] 
array[1] [1] 
array[1] [0]
```

```
array[0] [2] 
array[1] [2] 
array[2] [2]
array[2] [1] 
array[2] [0]
```

```
array[0] [3] 
array[1] [3] 
array[2] [3]
array[3] [3] 
array[3] [2] 
array[3] [1]
array[3] [0]
```

and so on, but i cant figure a proper for cycle to use to help me fill it, so I have to ask you guys for some help

Comment: What output does you program give? Please show the code, and where you think it is going wrong.

Comment: You need to traverse the right and bottom edges of, first a 1x1 square, then a 2x2 square, and so on, maintaining a variable with the current number to insert.

Comment: You have done the first step by writing down the sequence of indices. This should definitely help you to determine the rules that the sequence follows. You have also already divided it into blocks, which is good. However, your first block should be rather divided into a single line (array[0] [0]) as the first block and the remaining 3 lines (array[0][1], array[1][1], array[1][0]) as the second block. Then you should already see the structure among and within the blocks.

Comment: Split your first step into two, with the first being just `[0][0]` and you should see a clear pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I hope following code will work for you. I kept `printf` statement to show whether it stores correct value or not.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAT_DIM 4

int main()
{
    int loop1,loop2;
    int number = 0;
    int array[MAT_DIM][MAT_DIM];    
    for(loop1 = 0; loop1 < MAT_DIM; loop1++)
    {
        for(loop2 = 0; loop2 <= loop1; loop2++) 
        {
            array[loop2][loop1] = ++number;                 
            printf("%d  %d  %d \n", loop2, loop1, array[loop2][loop1]); 
        }


        for(loop2 = loop1-1; loop2 >= 0; loop2--) 
        {
            array[loop1][loop2] = ++number;
            printf("%d  %d  %d \n", loop1, loop2, array[loop1][loop2]);
        }
    }           
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

The code works as below :
We will need three `loops`

> 1. To increase the dimension of matrix  (Outer incremental loop)
> 2. Once dimension is fixed, Second loop will help to go upto next column. (Inner Incremental Loop)
> 3. Third loop will be required to come back to first row. (Inner decremental loop)

For for First Interation:
  We are storing array with 1*1 dimension. Here Inner decremental loop won't work

For for Second Interation:
  `loop1` becomes **1** so second column will be filled with next values till it reaches to second row.
   Here second inner loop will come in picture. This loop will start storing value from current row and decrementing the `loop2` value. As soon as it reaches to zero it will break.

So we are **storing column first with incrementing loop and row next with decrementing loop**. Same will continue until outer loop reaches to dimension in loop. Here It will go upto **4** as dimension of matrix.

Comment: Please explain the concepts instead of just writing the code for the guy.

Answer (score -2):

You are just doing an reverse L . so you need to do an column then a row.
See the code

`

```
int k=1;
//n= no of rows/cols
array[0][0]=1;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++) //column
    array[j][i]=k++;

    for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)  //row
    array[i][j]=k++;
}
```

`

Comment: Blatantly giving out the code will not help him. Try explaining how to do it and let him do it instead. :)

Comment: @WeatherVane

See I told he needs to do a reverse L thus fill a column and then a row and I am sorry if explaining and giving code is bad. Next time I will post just the explanation and not code but that time people will praise who post the code.

Comment: @cruxioneffux: And in other occasions that might be the right choice. Please "sense" the type of problem. This was most likely homework. Presenting him the solution just stops him from thinking further about it. It doesn't contain anything the guy couldn't have thought of himself (a new trick or API call). So he hasn't learned anything. In other occasions, where it's not about mechanically writing code, but about a technique/trick or best practice, it might be nice to illustrate it using code. Anyway, more code than explanation is never good. Read also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812

Comment: @WeatherVane :ok will try my best to help.